# MongoDB Sharded Cluster completely dropped database, now giving write errors

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I had a `Sharded Cluster` (3x3 replica sets, 3x mongos, 3xconfigs) setup on a few `Amazon AWS` instances with one database across them.

Yesterday, out of the blue, things on my application started acting strange, and when I logged into a `Mongos` and did 'show dbs', I got only 'local' back.

Now, if i try to insert any new document into a database using a `Mongos`, I get the following error:

```
WriteResult({
  "writeError" : {
    "code" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "exception: assertion src/mongo/s/shard.h:88"
  }
})
```

I can connect to all the `Mongo` instances (including configs and mongod), and they seem fine. But there are literally no traces of my database anywhere, even in the shard configuration.

Does anyone have any Idea what is going on?

I have backups, but when I try to `mongorestore` them I get the above error as well.

Thanks

Comment: Have you been taking backups and storing them somewhere off-server like S3? Have you been taking EBS snapshots?

Answer (score 0):

You should contact tech support from Amazon AWS, is the faster and cheaper way to fix you issue.